SqlAlchemy select statement where clause ignored

python 3.9
SqlAlchemy v2.0.0
SQLite

My SqlAlchemy model:
Base: DeclarativeMeta = declarative_base()

class TableAModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = "TableA"

    id: Mapped[uuid.UUID] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    some_other_field: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(nullable=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the object."""
        return (
            f"<TableA(id='{str(self.id)}', "
            f"some_other_field='{self.some_other_field}')>"
        )

select statement:
select_statement = select(TableAModel).where(
    TableAModel.id == some_existing_guid
)
results = self.sql_client.execute_select_statement(
    select_statement, select_first=True
)

db_layer.py:
def execute(self, statement: Select, select_first: bool = False):
    """Execute SELECT statement."""
    with self.__get_session__() as session:
        session.begin()
        try:
            result = session.execute(statement)
            if select_first:
                return result.first()
            return result.fetchall()
        except SQLAlchemyError as err:
            get_logger_adapter().error(
                "Error occurred during select:", exc_info=True
            )
            raise err

This follows the guide in SqlAlchemy's docs on how to perform a simple query by id. My where clause has no effect and always returns None. I have verified that the row exists with the correct id. A regular select with no where clause does return the existing row. I dumped the raw query to my console and the query looks correct.
SELECT "TableA".id, "TableA".some_other_field 
FROM "TableA" 
WHERE "TableA".id = :id_1


I only see this error in the statement object itself when debugging, it doesn't actually cause an execution error. I'll post a pic of the statement before being executed

Updated my question, realized the error has no bearing on the result. Previous error was possibly related to relationships.

What database are you using? FWIW, it seems to work for me with postgresql:// except that the rendered SELECT statement uses WHERE "TableA".id = %(id_1)s::UUID

i figured out the issue. I'm using sqlite and i had to change my data type to str instead of UUID. Any where clause i used just always failed until i changed it.

Had to swap out my primary key data type. I noticed in SQLite, my uuid mapped to varchar. As soon as i swapped my mapping to a string, my where clause started working.
id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)

